# json.dump() in a custom format?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[  
    {  
      '_item_id1':'0002',
      '_ticket_quantity1':1,
      '_showtime_id':5635775   
    },
    {  
      '_item_id2':'0001',
      '_ticket_quantity2':1,
       '_showtime_id':5635775    
    }
]
```

I want to do `json.dumps()` in this format:

```
data = json.dumps({
        'ticketTypes': [{
                'showtimeId': showtime_id,
                'id': item_id1,
                'quantity': ticket_quantity1
            },
       {
                'showtimeId': showtime_id,
                'id': item_id2,
                'quantity': ticket_quantity2
           }]
    })
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: it seems like it is already in that format, just assign the list of dicts to another dict with key as `ticketTypes`

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Keys are different.  like "id" for "item_id_1", "quantity" for "ticket_quantity".

Comment: Ah. I see the difference now. Please add that to your post

Comment: You need to build the fundamental structure yourself in Python before using `json.dumps()`. That means replacing the keys to the dictionaries yourself and incorporating your initial list into a dictionary against the `'ticketTypes'` key. If you're hoping for the key/value pairs of the dicts in you lists to conform to some order, you're out of luck; dictionaries have no definite order.

Comment: `json.dumps()` is driven by the data you pass it to convert to JSON format. That implies that you need to translate your list of dictionaries into a dictionary that will get converted into what you want ***before*** calling it—which seems like it would relatively easy for you to do, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to efficiently construct the desired data structure, and then dump it:

```
import json

input_data = [  
    {  
      '_item_id1':'0002',
      '_ticket_quantity1':1,
      '_showtime_id':5635775   
    },
    {  
      '_item_id2':'0001',
      '_ticket_quantity2':1,
       '_showtime_id':5635775    
    }
]

json_data = [{
    'showtimeId': '_showtime_id',
    'id': d['_item_id%s' % i],
    'quantity': d['_ticket_quantity%s' % i],
} for i, d in enumerate(input_data, start=1)]

print(json.dumps({
    'ticketTypes': json_data
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is more of a "translation" or "conversion" of information

But why is your data with

- "_item_id1"           <--- 1?  remove 1?
- "_ticket_quantity1"   <--- 1?  remove 1?
- "_showtime_id"        <--- nice!  could this be the id?
- "_item_id1"           <--- 2?  remove 2?
- "_ticket_quantity2"   <--- 2?  remove 2?
- "_showtime_id"        <--- nice!

All this data is in a list datatype, so there is no need to have the extra 1 or 2
if you remove it, then you can use the following

```
def convert2_Dict(data):
    ticketTypes = []
    for ticket in data:
       item_id = ticket[_item_id]
       ticket_quantity = ticket[_quantity]
       showtime_id = ticket[_showtime_id]
       ticketTypes.append([{"item_id":item_id}, \
                           {"ticket_quantity":ticket_quantity}, \ 
                           {"showtime_id":showtime_id}] )

     return ticketTypes
```

Otherwise, it is going to be a bit messier

```
def convert_Dict(data):
   ticketTypes = []
   for ticket in data:
      for key,value in ticket.iteritems():
         if key.find("_item_id"):             #now have to find the "string"
            item_id = ticket[_item_id]
         elif key.find("_ticket_quantity"):
            ticket_quantity = ticket[_quantity]
         elif key.find("_showtime_id")
            showtime_id = ticket[_showtime_id]
       ticketTypes.append([{"item_id":item_id}, \
                           {"ticket_quantity":ticket_quantity}, \ 
                           {"showtime_id":showtime_id}] )

    return ticketTypes
```

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation.  This worked for me.